# Updating A node in LinkedList by passing a String

Tags: java, linked-list

I am currently trying to search through a linked list and update the data in a certain node given a String name. I don understand where I am going wrong. I do not receive any error when I run the program but the data that I "update" never changes. 
My updateGpa method in my linkedlist class

```
public void updateGpa(String name, double gpa){
    Node<Student> temp = head;
    double foundData;
    boolean exists = false;
    for(int i = 0; (i < size) && !exists; i++){

        if(temp.data.getName().equals(name)){
            foundData =gpa;
            temp.data.setGpa(foundData);
            exists = true;
        }
        temp = getNode(i);

    }
}
```

My main method where I call the updateGpa method

```
    System.out.println("Update a students GPA by entering their name: ");
    student = in2.next();
    System.out.println("Enter " + student + "'s new GPA: ");
    gpa = in1.nextDouble();
    studentList.updateGpa(student, gpa);
    break;
```

Student list is my linked list.

Comment: Have you debugged to find out if `updateGpa()` thinks it has done anything?

Comment: When I debug it says successfully submitted

Comment: What is `in2` ? A `java.util.Random` object? If yes, you do you ensure that a student with a random name made of an integer value is in your list?

Comment: And from where do you get "successfully submitted"? It's nowhere in the code you've shown here.

Comment: in2 is a scanner object it reads in from the keyboard so I can store the student name in the variable student

Comment: Ok, and there is definitely a matching name in the list? That means, you read both input values properly (no spaces, etc.), you checked the GPA of the student before and after?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own problem, unfortunately I have to chalk it up to user error in my main method I have student = in2.next where it should have been in2.nextLine It was only reading in the first name rather than the first and last name so when it was comparing the string in the updateGpa method it would never find a match because the string wasn't exactly equal. Sorry to waste your time but thank you for your input